# Rails: Cache Sweepers and Expiring Fragments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fragment-caching, sweeper

I have a form where an admin can create a new user, in this form there is a `remote: true`. When the user is successfully created the section on the page that displays all of the users is updated. This is not happening in Production since I have caching turned on...

create.js.erb:

```
<% if @user.valid? %>
    <% type = (@user.type == "Athlete" ? "athletes" : "high_school_coaches" ) %> 
      alert("<%= @user.email %> created!");
      $('form#new_user').find('input:not(:hidden, :submit)').val('');
      $('.<%= type %>-container').html("<%= j render \"school_admin/#{type}/all\", users: @users.in_groups_of(3, false) %>")
<% else %>
  alert("<%= @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence %>");
<% end %>
```

UserSweeper:

```
class UserSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Athlete, HighSchoolCoach

  def after_create(record)
    expire_cache(record)
  end

  def after_update(record)
    expire_cache(record)
  end

  def expire_cache(record)
    type = record.is_a?(HighSchoolCoach) ? "coach" : "athlete"
    expire_fragment("all_school_admin_#{type.pluralize}")
  end
end
```

In production `$('.<%= type %>-container').html("<%= j render \"school_admin/#{type}/all\", users: @users.in_groups_of(3, false) %>")` this is not working because I have the following cache fragment in the view:

```
<% cache('all_school_admin_athletes') do %>
  <% users.each do |row_users| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% row_users.each do |user| %>
        <%= render user %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}
  #{config.root}/lib
  #{config.root}/app/models
  #{config.root}/app/models/concerns
  #{config.root}/app/sweepers
)

# Activate observers that should always be running.
config.active_record.observers = :user_sweeper
```

Anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

Forgot to add this to my Controller:

`cache_sweeper :user_sweeper, only: [:create]`